# Changing the color of the text and cursor in input box

Tags: html, css

When a user clicks in the box below, the cursor and typed text are black.  How could I make them the color of `#DE2A00` ?

```
<div class="usernameformfield"><input tabindex="1" accesskey="u" name="username" type="text" maxlength="35" id="username" /></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<style>
#username {
    color: #DE2A00;
}
</style>
```

Or you could have the color change when a user clicks on the field like so:

```
<script type=text/javascript src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type=text/javascript>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#username').click(function(){
            $(this).css({'color': '#DE2A00'});
        });
    });
</script>
```

It depends on what you want, I would check out this reference to start playing around with some things:

[w3schools](http://w3schools.com/html5/html5_reference.asp)

and

[css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Just use CSS:

```
#username{color:#000;} /* black when not with focus */
#username:focus{color:#de2a00;} /* green when input has focus - only affects this specific input */
```

Answer (score 0):

You could these little JavaScripts:

```
onfocus="this.style.background = '#DE2A00'" onblur="this.style.background = 'white'"
```

Comment: You are setting the background colour - question was for foreground.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't look closely enough.

Answer (score 0):

A little shorter one:

```
input:focus { color: #DE2A00  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you need the text inside the text box in that color, if so do this

```
 <input...type="text"...style="color: #DE2A00;"/></div>
```

Comment: inline styles are evil - maintenance nightmare.